# Join 5 tables in mysql to show two SUM columns of two different tables in the same query

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, multiple-tables

I am working in a project to control the stock of items which are used in different tasks. Each task has one or more warehouses, each warehouse receives an input of items that are needed to complete de task, and finally the real item qtys used for the task are in the used_items table.

TABLES

```
task:
taskId  | name 
-----------------

warehouse: 
warehous_id  | taskId
----------------------

inputs:
itemId |  qty  |  warehouse_id
--------------------------------


items:
itemId  | itemName
--------------------


used:
itemId |  qty   |  taskId
-----------------------------
```

I'm trying to obtain a report for the items of certain task using the following querys:

QUERY1: items used in a sepecific task (task 1 for example):

```
SELECT t.taskId
     , it.itemId
     , it.itemName
     , SUM(u.qty) total_used 
  FROM items it
     , task t
     , used u
 WHERE it.itemId = u.itemId 
   AND t.taskId = u.taskId 
   AND t.taskId = 1
 GROUP 
    BY it.itemId
```

this query gives the following result:

```
taskId itemId itemName total_used
1       2       item2     10
1       3       item3      1
1       4       item4      6
1       5       item5      6
1       6       item6      2
1       8       item8      9
1       9       item9      4
1      10       item10     7
```

This result is correct. 8 items used.

QUERY2: input of items for a sepecific task (task 1 for example):

```
SELECT t.taskId
     , it.itemId
     , it.itemName
     , SUM(ip.qty) total_input
  FROM items it
     , task t
     , inputs ip
     , warehouse w
 WHERE it.itemId=ip.itemId 
   AND t.taskId=w.taskId 
   AND w.warehouseId=ip.warehouseId 
   AND t.taskId=1
 GROUP 
    BY it.itemId
```

this query gives the following result:

```
taskId itemId itemName total_input
1         1     item1      24
1         2     item2      26
1         3     item3      21
1         4     item4      18
1         5     item5      22
1         6     item6       3
1         7     item7      17
1         8     item8      12
1         9     item9      17
1        10     item10     20
```

This result is correct. 10 input items.

both queries generates correct results. But the problem comes when I try to combine both queries to show two columns with the SUM of each one, the result is not ok.

Combined query:

```
SELECT t.taskId
     , it.itemId
     , it.itemName
     , SUM(ip.qty) total_input
     , SUM(u.qty) total_used
  FROM items it
     , task t
     , inputs ip
     , warehouse w
     , used u
 WHERE it.itemId=ip.itemId 
   AND t.taskId=w.taskId 
   AND w.warehouseId=ip.warehouseId 
   AND u.itemId=it.itemId 
   AND u.taskId=t.taskId 
   AND t.taskId=1
 GROUP 
    BY it.itemId
```

result:

```
taskId itemId itemName total_input total_used
1       2       item2       52       90
1       3       item3       21       7
1       4       item4       18       24
1       5       item5       22       30
1       6       item6       3        4
1       8       item8       12       27
1       9       item9       17       20
1       10      item10      20       35
```

This generates a wrong result, first because it only shows 8 columns instead of 10, and also the totals are wrong. I've searched and tried a lot on how to do this right, but i only found examples of subqueries or left join with two tables, which is simpler, but when it comes with 5 tables with all the relations involved, i don´t know how to do it.

i appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

First i'd tranform Query 1 and Query 2 using JOIN, this makes it much more readable.

Example (see http://www.sql-join.com/):

```
select order_date, order_amount
from customers
join orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
```

Then either create a view for Query1 and Query2:

```
CREATE VIEW `myView1` AS
    select order_date, order_amount
    from customers
    join orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
```

Then you could do a new query JOINING both views.

Good luck :)

Comment: Sorry André, this did not answer my question because the problem is more complex when adding more tables and its relations, but thanks for trying to help me!